# Whenever gem 'failed to load command: rake'

Tags: ruby, docker, cron, ruby-on-rails-3.2, whenever

looking for some help.

I am running a rails app (v3.2.5) with the `whenever` gem (v0.9.7) and `rake` (v11.2.2). I am also doing this in a docker container image `ruby:2.3` (`cron` was installed and `bundle install` was ran)

Here is my `schedule.rb`

```
set :environment, ENV['RAILS_ENV']

every '*/2 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 * * 1-5' do
    rake "import_csv", output: {:error => 'log/import_csv_errors.log', :standard => 'log/import_csv.log'}'
end
```

*note* `RAILS_ENV` is set at container launch to `development`

Here is my cron job that is on the container after build (`crontab -l`):

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /usr/src/app/config/schedule.rb
*/2 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 * * 1-5 /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /usr/src/app && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake import_csv --silent >> log/import_csv.log 2>> log/import_csv_errors.log'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /usr/src/app/config/schedule.rb
```

When this cron job runs, the logs return:

**import_csv_errors.log**

```
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-11.2.2 in any of the sources
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:95:in `block in materialize'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `map!'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `materialize'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `requested_specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:19:in `requested_specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:14:in `setup'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:95:in `setup'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

**import_csv.log**

```
bundler: failed to load command: rake (/usr/local/bin/rake)
```

Now here is the odd thing. If I copy the cron job command:

```
/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /usr/src/app && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake import_csv --silent >> log/import_csv.log 2>> log/import_csv_errors.log'
```

and run this in the container, it works fine, but if the cron job runs it, I get thos errors in the logs!!! I am at a lost here...

I've tried adding

```
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
env :GEM_PATH, '/usr/local/bundle'
```

to the top of `schedule.rb` and I tried doing

```
command 'cd /usr/src/app && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake import_csv --silent >> log/import_csv.log 2>> log/import_csv_errors.log'
```

Instead of using `rake` in the task and I get the same errors..

Any help is appriciated

Comment: man i am stuck on the same error it has nothing to do with docker, if you do rake --help, it will run fine but for other rake tasks it gives this error

Comment: Can you do `find / -name "gems"` and show me the output

Comment: I just answered my issue below in this thread. Please review @user1735921

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated my rake version and it worked for me. Below are the steps I followed:

```
sudo bundle update rake
sudo bundle install
```

Open a Rakefile and replace the line `rake/rdoctask` with `require 'rdoc/task'`.

Answer (score 10):

I've fixed the same error by modifying the `Dockerfile` with:

```
RUN gem update --system 2.6.12
RUN gem install bundler --version 1.14.6
```

And `schedule.rb`:

```
ENV.each { |k, v| env(k, v) }
```

Comment: Adding the Environment Variables to cronjob solves the problem.

Comment: +1 on the `ENV.each { ... }` — that did the trick. I'd been fussing with individual env variables and not sure why I didn't think of that (much easier) approach

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by using a different image and building as I needed it instead of using docker hub image `ruby:2.x`.

Dockerfile (edited to fit thread):

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Installs needed to run rails on ubuntu 14.04 (must use mysql 5.6 or 5.5):
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2 curl git build-essential libmysqlclient-dev mysql-server-5.6 nodejs make
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ruby-dev zlib1g-dev
RUN gem install rails --version 3.2.5 --no-ri --no-rdoc

# Update ruby to v2.2 (optional)
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common && apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ruby2.2

# Install cron
RUN apt-get install -y cron

# Finish the build
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# If you code is in the same directory you ran docker build then:
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN bundle install
RUN whenever --update-crontab
CMD ["passenger start"]
```